# What is the maximum character count that can be stored in a csv column?

Tags: python, csv

I'm saving a large list (list of strings/paragraphs) in a csv's column. I can see some that for some rows, where the data is supposed to be huge, the column is empty.

What is the maximum character length that can be stored in a csv file?

I'm using csv_reader. What is the solution of storing such large character-length values in csv ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any limit. Python has no problem with multi-megabyte strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit for .csv file as it is just a text file. But there is a limit in `csv` module. You can check it like this:

```
import csv

csv.field_size_limit()
```

and set a new limit with the same function, e.x.:

```
import sys

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
```